# "В тысячу раз и более"

Tags: лексика

Как правильно? "В тысячу раз и более" или "В тысячу и более раз".

Comment: В тысячу - это еще нечего. Меня особенно умиляют фразы "более 41 раза". Думаю, так все-таки говорить нельзя, хотя с точки зрения математики это допустимо.  

Помню, я приводила студентам на информатике такой пример. Как воспримет фразу "Ему меньше 50 лет" человек и компьютер. Для второго меньше 50 - это от 0 до 49. Для первого - где-то 47-48-49. В крайнем случае - 45, но это уже вряд ли.

Comment: Привет вам от компьютера. "Мешьше пятидесяти" для меня - это от 0 до 49 с одинадцатью месяцами. А чем вам 41 год не понравился? 
  
Что меня дестительно бесит, так это постонянное использование это обороты типа "Этот шампунь повышает лохматость более дух раз". Кажется, рекламщики уже окончательно забыли правильную форму... Хотя повышение лохматости или там шелковистости даже на 73.1% тоже не вызывает положительных эмоций. Но по другим причинам.

Comment: Хуже всего, что за столько лет такой рекламы люди воспринимают  фразы типа "повышает ...до двух раз" как правильные.

Comment: Дык фразы-то правильные. Смысл другой.   
...  
На гусельный прибудем зов.    
Прощай, Гусляр! До трех разов.    
У нас закон — прощать».    
...  
(Марина)

Comment: Потому и неправильные. Имеется в виду - в два раза.

Comment: Я бы сказал : "Более, чем в тысячу раз"

Comment: @behemothus, не 41 год, а 41 раз. Конечно, в технической документации можно написать и "более, чем в 41,5 раз". Но в обыденной речи говорят "более" подразумевая "примерно, но не меньше". Поэтому используются круглые числа. Или небольшие (2, 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по Розенталю, можно так и этак. Напрямую он об этом не пишет, однако, говоря об управлении существительным, упоминает возможность перестановки ("два и более варианта", затем "ср. возможность перестановки: два варианта и более").